# VB.Net How to write fraction in a label?

Tags: vb.net, label, fractions

What method do I have to use to write fraction e.g. ½ in a label using VB.Net?

Comment: Do you just want the fractions ¼, ½ and ¾? Do you want a general case for any fractions?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a better option which is using RichTextBox instead of using Label. Drag a RichTextBox onto a Form, and type fraction using shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetFraction(ByVal d As Double) As String
    ' Get the initial denominator: 1 * (10 ^ decimal portion length)
    Dim Denom As Int32 = CInt(1 * (10 ^ d.ToString.Split("."c)(1).Length))

    ' Get the initial numerator: integer portion of the number
    Dim Numer As Int32 = CInt(d.ToString.Split("."c)(1))

    ' Use the Euclidean algorithm to find the gcd
    Dim a As Int32 = Numer
    Dim b As Int32 = Denom
    Dim t As Int32 = 0 ' t is a value holder

    ' Euclidean algorithm
    While b <> 0
        t = b
        b = a Mod b
        a = t
    End While

    'Get whole part of the number
    Dim Whole As String = d.ToString.Split("."c)(0)

    ' Return our answer
     Return Whole & " " & (Numer / a) & "/" & (Denom / a)

End Function
```

label.text = GetFraction(0.5)

This function will convert 0.5 to 1/2 in your label
The function will return 0 1/2
To omit the 0 change - do not return  "Whole"